# Как изменить версию приложения?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image: Скриншот ошибки]

Старое приложение в build gradle имеет vercion code = 170  а version name = 0.1.170
В новом пробую установить 171 и 0.1.171 соответственно
Получаю ошибку как на скриншоте.
Так же в старом приложении в android manifest присутствует следующее

```
  package="ru.#########"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="0.1.5" >
```

Comment: И в чём проблема? Просит же удалить старое приложение

Comment: Это означает, что новая версия подписана другим ключом. То есть стоял релиз, а вы ставите дебаг или наоборот. Или вы вообще ключ, которым подписывали прошлую версию, не сохранили? - тогда на маркет вам придётся выкладывать "новое" приложение (менять пакет и название).

Comment: У нас есть исходник старой версии, не могли бы вы нам подсказать как собрать и подписать нужным ключем ? Может связаться(почта\telegram\skype), готовы оплатить консультацию